# Weird $http GET response on Android device with Crosswalk

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to get some data in json format from an API, using angularjs. Everything works perfectly on iOS and in browser, but I am getting a weird response on my Android device. The request is made like this:

```
$http({
    url: baseUrl, 
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    params: {
          authKey: myAuthKey,
          id: myId,
          format: "json"
    }
})
.success(function(data, status){
     console.log("Success", data); // Here the output is different on Android
     orderData(data);
})
.error(function(data, status){
     console.log("Error");
     console.log(data,status);
});
```

The request is always **successful** and returns an **object** as expected on iOS and in desktop browser. But when I log the data on my Android device I get the following output:

```
>     Success <html>
>     <head>
>     </head>
>     <body>
>     <script>
>     var wwwurl='www.mywifiext.com/welcome.htm';
>     function check_mobile_device()
>     {
>     if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPhone") != -1)
>     return 1;
>     else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Android") != -1)
>     return 1;
>     else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Windows Phone") != -1)
>     return 1;
>     else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("iPad") != -1 )
>     return 0;
>     else
>     return 0;
>     }
>     if(check_mobile_device() == '1')
>     top.location.href="http://www.mywifiext.net/mobile_welcome.htm";
>     else
>     top.location.href="http://www.mywifiext.net/welcome.htm";
>     </script>
>     </body>
>     </html>
```

What is this, some weird html response refering to some router? I have tested on different wifi networks and it is the same with the device's 3G connection.

I've added crosswalk to my project recently and it uses the `cordova-plugin-whitelist`, can it possibly have something to do with this? Or could this be a bug on the API-side?

**EDIT:** Reverting to the default browser made it work. But why? How can I get it to work with Crosswalk?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String url = "http://my-json-feed";

JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest
    (Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
    Log.v("Response: ", response.toString());
}
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
});
```

Comment: how you are calling ajax request in the android side?

Comment: I'm using [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) which technically is a web application running in a native shell.

Answer (score 0):

Has nothing to do with your code.

You're in an open WiFi network which requires authentication via an HTML page. When you're requesting resources via HTTP and are not yet authenticated on the WiFi access point, you're redirected to a welcome page.

Possible Solution:

Open a web browser and any web page. You'll be redirected to the welcome page (that you downloaded with your `$http.get()`). Fill in you're access data for the network and accept the conditions. After that, you're Cordova app should work the way you expect.

For your users:

Maybe some kind of error handling could help your users when they get into similar situations. You could add an http interceptor dealing with non-JSON responses and telling the user that they probably have to check their network and login to the access point.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I also thought so first. But then, I am not using an open WiFi network. And again, it is the same error with the phones 3G connection. One other thing is that I am getting data from other API:s in my applications that works just fine, just this one returns this error. Removing crosswalk makes it work but I have no idea why.

Comment: Do you think it might be possible that the resource is cached in your crosswalk instance?